# Cannot use boolean modifier to cut out difference of 2 objects

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, proportional-editing

I have to objects which I'll paste below. Using the boolean modifier I need to use the 'difference' setting to cut out the space that the 2 objects have in common. The first object is a complicated gear which prevents the process from working. Maybe I can change the gear into another kind of object. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Gear]

[image: Shaft]

Comment: hello, have you try all the different options of the boolean? maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello.. I just added the file through that app.. I hope you got it. Thank you

Comment: you need to share the link it will give you  ;)

Comment: It doesn't provide a link after I upload. I am using a Mac

Comment: copy paste the URL address it gives once you've uploaded

Comment: There's a bug. It doesn't give a URL

Comment: oh ok or use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=JVVS8NGY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/JVVS8NGY/)

Comment: I had success by cutting the shaft in half THEN using the boolean modifier. I just have to do the same thing to the other side. Bugs, bugs, bugs. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the scale of both your objects, recalculate the normals, use *Boolean/Difference/Solver Exact* and scale a bit so that faces don't overlap and it seems to work. If the scale is a problem maybe try with a simpler topology?

[image]

Comment: when you say "apply scale" could you be more specific? Also, do I change the normals outside or inside?

Comment: I really can't understand your directions but I have been able to isolate things. Would you be able to check this file out? Maybe there's a good solution.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=XX5rbpvm" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XX5rbpvm/)

Comment: To apply scale, select the object in Object mode and press Ctrl A > Apply Scale. For the normals, go in Edit mode, select all and press Shift N. But there is still a problem as you have faces overlapping so you need to scale the object a bit so that they stop overlapping.